# Default language isn't in list of iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I would like to distribute iOS app for Czech AppStore and set default language of app as Czech, but in the list of languages isn't Czech language. How to send app for validation with czech localization and describe. Is it possible or app must be in english and czech?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have to only select english, and localize it for Czech ( I mean the language in the app )